# На чём пишут утилиты под Android?

Tags: android, linux

Возможно вопрос не корректный, но всё же. В Android есть папка /system/bin, в который находятся файлы-утилиты. Так вот, на каком языке программирования они написаны ?

Comment: скорее всего на C/C++.

Comment: Хочешь написать что-то своё или просто интересно?

Comment: Скорее всего своё. Задался целью написать Root exploit. Вот и интересуюсь, с чем иметь дело)

Comment: Тогда тебе в http://source.android.com/

Comment: Да не в этом дело, просто я хочу написать утилиту командную. Допустим вводишь myutil checkroot и у тебя типо Рут права появляются

Comment: Я так понимаю, что с программированием ты не знаком и ничего из прикладного\системного софта никогда не писал, но хочешь сразу написать M3g@ c001 s0ft?

Comment: Насчёт системного софта вы правы. А так программирую на Java, и врятли на нём напишешь такую утилиту

Comment: Для того, чтобы получить рута на оригинальной прошивке - надо найти в ней уязвимость, которая или допущена по ошибке или оставлена для тестирования\по глупости\со злым умыслом. Чтобы найти уявзимость - нужно читать исходники (самое начало пути). Ссылку выше я уже дал. Есть ещё куча других способов, но сорцы дают понять что и как работает. Но ИМХО - забей. Нужен рут, иди на 4pda и качни готовую рутованную прошивку на свой мобильник.

Comment: Уважаемый, я просто привёл пример насчёт рута. Я хотел узнать как эти утилиты пишут? Какой ЯП? На чём пишут, и так далее...

Comment: Качни сорцы и посмотри глазами. Или почитай в википедии - там тоже написано.

Comment: Если нетрудно, киньте ссылочку на wiki

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)

Comment: Исходники можешь ещё [тут](android.googlesource.com) посмотреть.